# Uncaught ReferenceError: backgroundGeolocation is not defined cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am new in AngularJS and Ionic. I am building an app in Ionic (version 1) which will collect the GPS location of the device in the background. I am trying to use [cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation](https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation) plugin for this purpose. But I am getting an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: backgroundGeolocation is not defined.`

My app.js

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services', 'firebase', 'ngMaterial'])


.factory('BackgroundGeolocationService', ['$q', '$http', function ($q, $http) {
  var callbackFn = function(location) {
      $http({
          //request options to send data to server
      });
    backgroundGeolocation.finish();
  },

  failureFn = function(error) {
    console.log('BackgroundGeoLocation error ' + JSON.stringify(error));
  },

  //Enable background geolocation
  start = function () {
      //save settings (background tracking is enabled) in local storage
    window.localStorage.setItem('bgGPS', 1);

    //...........ERROR IS ON THE FOLLOWING LINE.........    
    backgroundGeolocation.configure(callbackFn, failureFn, {
      desiredAccuracy: 10,
      stationaryRadius: 20,
      distanceFilter: 30,
      locationService: 'ANDROID_DISTANCE_FILTER',
      debug: false,
      stopOnTerminate: false
    });

    backgroundGeolocation.start();
  };

  return {
    start: start,

      // Initialize service and enable background geolocation by default
    init: function () {
      var bgGPS = window.localStorage.getItem('bgGPS');
      if (bgGPS == 1 || bgGPS == null) {
        start();
      }
    },

      // Stop data tracking
    stop: function () {
      window.localStorage.setItem('bgGPS', 0);
      backgroundGeolocation.stop();
    }
  }
}])


.run(function($ionicPlatform, BackgroundGeolocationService) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
      BackgroundGeolocationService.init();
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Cordova device ready event is getting fired and you have placed the plugin code inside platform ready function?

Comment: @Gandhi I called the factory inside $ionicPlatform.ready

Comment: did u managed to debug using chrome inspect device option? I guess that will give you more info on this

Answer (score 3):

The plugin is [exposed via the `backgroundGeolocation` global namespace](https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation/blob/master/plugin.xml#L17) but you are referencing it as `backgroundGeoLocation`.

Note the difference: you are using a capital L. Javascript is case-sensitive so you need to be careful with case.

Comment: I first thought the issue was solved but it wasn't. The problem is sill there. Is there any other mistakes?

Comment: Are you testing on Android or iOS device? I would connect the relevant remote debugging tool to the Webview (Chrome or Safari) and place breakpoints allowing you to step through and inspect the code.

Comment: I am testing in android and I am using chrome

Comment: Then I would connect the device via USB and use Chrome Dev tools to inspect and debug the Webview

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered issues with Ionic/Cordova plugins before. For me the solution was to do the following:

**ionic platform rm android**

**ionic platform add android**

You can then run **ionic run android --device** and wait for the app to run on your android device. Once it loads, open up Chrome browser and type in *Chome://Inspect* into the URL bar.  Find your App Webview and click *Inspect* This will open up the usual Chrome Dev Tools, where you can find any console logs, missing plugins, errors etc.